# Azure Kubernetes: TLS handshake timeout

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-container-service

I created a new cluster as per the [Azure guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough) and created the cluster without issue but when I enter the `kubectl get nodes` to list the nodes I only get this response `Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout`.

I tried once in the Cloud Shell and once on my machine using the latest version of the Azure CLI (2.0.20).

I saw that there was a similar earlier issue regarding [Service Principal credentials](https://github.com/Azure/ACS/issues/4), which I updated but that didn't seem to solve my issue either.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you please try to SSH to k8s master and run `kubectl get nodes`?

Comment: By the way, please run this script on your k8s master `journalctl -u kubelet | grep --text autorest` and put the output in your question, thanks:)

Comment: I suppose it's in `west us 2`? there is capacity issue in that region which is related to the message you see.

Comment: My team is in U.S. East and experiencing this issue still (June). I am starting to collect info on this issue over here and could use your help if your Cluster(s) are also having this problem.  Will update solutions as I find them:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726534/unable-to-connect-net-http-tls-handshake-timeout-why-cant-kubectl-connect

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this one for me was to scale the nodes up — and then back down — for my impacted Cluster from the Azure Kubernetes service blade web console.

## Workaround / Potential Solution

1. Log into the Azure Console — Kubernetes Service blade.
2. Scale your cluster up by 1 node.
3. Wait for scale to complete and attempt to connect (you should be able to).
4. Scale your cluster back down to the normal size to avoid cost increases.

Total time it took me ~2 mins.

### More Background Info on the Issue

Also added this solution to the full ticket description write up that I posted over here (if you want more info have a read):

['Unable to connect Net/http: TLS handshake timeout' — Why can't Kubectl connect to Azure Kubernetes server? (AKS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726534/unable-to-connect-net-http-tls-handshake-timeout-why-cant-kubectl-connect)

Answer (score 1):

Piling on: we are adding capacity as fast as possible for the preview.

Answer (score 1):

For now, Azure AKS still in preview. We have a general service outage in West US 2 that we are investigating.

During the time we investigate, cluster creations in West US 2 will **not** be possible and existing customers might not work.

We will **update** [this thread](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/blob/master/annoucements/service_outage_2017-11-09.md) when we fix the issue.

We apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.